# How to print lines from a file with a leading string using Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm very new to Perl. I've started this tutorial http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/. There's an exercise in the filehandling section which reads:

> Modify the above program so that the
>   entire file is printed with a # symbol
>   at the beginning of each line. You
>   should only have to add one line and
>   modify another. Use the $" variable.

This is the program:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
#
# Program to open the password file, read it in,
# print it, and close it again.

$file = '/etc/passwd';      # Name the file
open(INFO, $file);      # Open the file
@lines = <INFO>;        # Read it into an array
close(INFO);            # Close the file
print @lines;           # Print the array
```

Could someone help me with this very easy task? Also, what does it mean when it mentions the $" variable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show some of the things you've tried, or thought of?  The `$"` variable is a Perl special variable, and if you have `use English;` at the top of your file you can call it `$LIST_SEPARATOR`, which may help you look it up.

Comment: Did you read the big bold note at the start of that tutorial? Why would you use a tutorial that specifically says that it's out of date? Far better to use the resources listed at http://learn.perl.org/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to this is understanding the use of the `$"` variable (note: this is not the same as the `$_` variable). The `$"` variable:

> This is the separator used between list elements when an array variable 
>   is interpolated into a double-quoted string. Normally, its value is a space 
>   character.

What does this mean? It means that there is a way to convert an array of items into a string context, with each item seperated by a special character. By default, that special character is a space...but we can change what that special character is by changing the `$"` variable.

**SPOILER ALERT**

**The below text contains the solution to the exercise!**

**SPOILER ALERT**

So, the first part of this exercise is to print out the file in a string context, instead of an array. Let's pretend we have a fake file whose contents are:

```
[/etc/passwd]
User1
User2
User3

[exercise.pl]
#!/usr/local/bin/perl   
#   
# Program to open the password file, read it in,   
# print it, and close it again.      
$file = '/etc/passwd';      # Name the file   
open(INFO, $file);          # Open the file   
@lines = <INFO>;            # Read it into an array   
close(INFO);                # Close the file   
print "@lines";             # Print the array   <---- Notice the double quotes

[RESULT]
User1
 User2
 User3
```

Notice that space added in between the elements? That's because when we interpolate the array into a string context, the `$"` variable comes into play, and adds a space in between each element as it is concatenated. What we need to do *next* is change that space into a "#". We can change the `$"` variable before printing to do this:

```
[exercise.pl]
#!/usr/local/bin/perl   
#   
# Program to open the password file, read it in,   
# print it, and close it again.      
$file = '/etc/passwd';      # Name the file   
open(INFO, $file);          # Open the file   
@lines = <INFO>;            # Read it into an array   
close(INFO);                # Close the file
$" = "#";                   # Change $"         <---- This line has been added!
print "@lines";             # Print the array   <---- Notice the double quotes

[RESULT]
User1
#User2
#User3
```

Allright! We're almost there. The last bit is to get a "#" in front of the very first line. Because `$"` changes the *seperator* between elements, it doesn't affect the very first line! We can finish this off by changing the `print` statement to print a "#" followed by the contents of the file:

```
[exercise.pl]
#!/usr/local/bin/perl   
#   
# Program to open the password file, read it in,   
# print it, and close it again.      
$file = '/etc/passwd';      # Name the file   
open(INFO, $file);          # Open the file   
@lines = <INFO>;            # Read it into an array   
close(INFO);                # Close the file
$" = "#";                   # Change $"         <---- This line has been added!
print "#" . "@lines";       # Print the array   <---- Notice the double quotes

[RESULT]
#User1
#User2
#User3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This answer my first question here. Will use in the future. Will also use an up to date Perl tutorial! Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you should look up the [`$"` variable in perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24LIST_SEPARATOR) and see what it does. If you do that, the rest is easy.

Comment: @mu is too short: Baah, you spoiled the search exercise.

Comment: @mu is too short: It's all right, but I left the link out on purpose, so he would look for himself.